# runtime error in vc++ but not in gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, runtime, visual-studio-2017

I have this program which runs perfectly using gcc but gives "vector subscript out of range" runtime error with visual studio 2017. On using a debugger, it shows error on the function call `countWords(&v, "hello");`. How can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Trie {
    int prefixes;
    int words;
    vector<Trie*> edges;
};

typedef Trie vertex;

void initialize(vertex *v)
{
    v->words = 0;
    v->prefixes = 0;
    v->edges.resize(26);
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        v->edges[i] = nullptr;
    }
}

void addWord(vertex* v, string word)
{
    if (word == "")
    {
        v->words++;
    }
    else
    {
        v->prefixes++;
        int k = word[0] - 'a' - 1;
        if (v->edges[k] == nullptr)
        {
            v->edges[k] = new Trie;
            initialize(v->edges[k]);
        }
        int word_len = word.length();
        addWord(v->edges[k], word.substr(1, word_len - 1));
    }
}

int countWords(vertex* v, string word)
{

    char k = word[0];
    if (word == "")
        return v->words;
    else if (v->edges[k] == nullptr)
        return 0;
    else
        return countWords(v->edges[k], word.substr(1, word.length() - 1));
}

int main()
{
    Trie v;
    initialize(&v);
    addWord(&v, "hello");
    countWords(&v, "hello");
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio marketing name != compiler version. Visual Studio is the IDE and MSVC is the compiler that you can install along with Visual Studio - they're separate things. Please give both GCC's version and MSVC's version.

Comment: gcc 6.0 and msvc 19.10.25019

Comment: MSVC++ has the iterator debugging feature enabled by default in the Debug build, useful to catch the UB in this program.  The debugger can easily show you what went wrong from the stack trace.  `edges` has 26 elements, presumably meant for 'A'..'Z'.  But you are indexing it with 'h', index 104.  Kaboom.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree, but just a detail, won't the index be 104? See my answer (I am asking, since it might be that I am wrong).

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks that explains it.

Comment: did you mean "char k = word[0] - 'a';  "?

Comment: @Serge -- `word[0] - 'a` **only** if you promise to never, ever try to compile this code for a system that doesn't use ASCII.

Comment: Yes, but the program already does it  in 'addWord', but forgets to do the same in the 'countWords'. So, it is already dealing with ascii

Comment: Use `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` to get an error with gcc as well.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Thanks it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well here:

```
int countWords(vertex* v, string word)
{

    char k = word[0];
    ...
        else if (v->edges[k] == nullptr)
    ...
        return countWords(v->edges[k], word.substr(1, word.length() - 1));
}
```

`k` is equal to 'h', which is not valid for indexing your vector called `edges`, causing:

> vector subscript out of range

as you mentioned.

`h` will give [index 104](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif), and your vector has a size of 26, thus you definitely go out of bounds, causing *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: but then why would it run if compiled using gcc?

Comment: This is what happens with Undefined Behavior @XZ6H, you can't tell for sure what will happen, sometimes it will crash, sometimes it will not!

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Now I get it.

Comment: My main question was about difference in compilers but anyway your answer solves the problem.